# How to increment numbers in filenames for multiple files without overwriting?

Tags: python

I was trying to rename the files using Python, but I got an unexpected result. I was renaming 10 files but in the end I got only 5 files.

How to rename files correctly using Python?

```py
import os

start = 0
end  = 10
increment = 5 # This should work for 5 or 50 both

folder = 'catalog'
z = 1.5

# create file
if not os.path.exists('catalog'):
    os.mkdirs('catalog')

for i in range(start,end):
    with open(f'catalog/catalog_z1.5_{i:03d}.txt','w') as fo:
        fo.write(str(i))

# rename files
for i in range(start,end+1,1):
    f = '{}/{}_z{:.1f}_{:03d}.txt'.format(folder,folder,z,i)
    f2 = '{}/{}_z{:.1f}_{:03d}.txt'.format(folder,folder,z,i+increment)

    print(f)
    print(f2)
    print()
    os.rename(f,f2)
```

Note:

Here I have 10 files.
The print shows correct file names, but when I look at the Finder there are only five files.
How to fix the problem?

Comment: Isolate the error and you will most likely find the correct answer. In what case does the incorrect renaming take place ..

Comment: @iqmaker it does not give an error. The print statement is correct. ONLY when I check files on computer they are wrong.

Comment: Your code raises an exception on my machine so you must be catching the error then suppressing it somewhere. Unless you're on Unix in which case the file gets overwritten thus you'd best see @Pierre-D's answer below.

Comment: site note: you can replace the initial dir creation in the simpler: `os.makedirs(folder, exist_ok=True)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at what's happening:

```
start = 0
end  = 10
increment = 5 # This should work for 5 or 50 both

folder = 'catalog'
z = 1.5

for i in range(start,end+1,1):
    f = '{}/{}_z{:.1f}_{:03d}.txt'.format(folder,folder,z,i)
    f2 = '{}/{}_z{:.1f}_{:03d}.txt'.format(folder,folder,z,i+increment)
    print(f'{f} -> {f2}')
```

Output:

```
catalog/catalog_z1.5_000.txt -> catalog/catalog_z1.5_005.txt
catalog/catalog_z1.5_001.txt -> catalog/catalog_z1.5_006.txt
catalog/catalog_z1.5_002.txt -> catalog/catalog_z1.5_007.txt
catalog/catalog_z1.5_003.txt -> catalog/catalog_z1.5_008.txt
catalog/catalog_z1.5_004.txt -> catalog/catalog_z1.5_009.txt
catalog/catalog_z1.5_005.txt -> catalog/catalog_z1.5_010.txt
catalog/catalog_z1.5_006.txt -> catalog/catalog_z1.5_011.txt
catalog/catalog_z1.5_007.txt -> catalog/catalog_z1.5_012.txt
catalog/catalog_z1.5_008.txt -> catalog/catalog_z1.5_013.txt
catalog/catalog_z1.5_009.txt -> catalog/catalog_z1.5_014.txt
catalog/catalog_z1.5_010.txt -> catalog/catalog_z1.5_015.txt
```

So, following for example the `000.txt` file, it first gets renamed into `005.txt` (clobbering the original `005.txt` file). Then it becomes `010.txt`, etc.

**How to fix it**

In your specific case, you can go in reverse, since the renamed file is always higher (`i+increment`) than the original: replace your for loop into `for i in reversed(range(start, end+1)):`

However, *in the general case*, it is advisable to clearly distinguish original files from transformed (or here, renamed) files to ensure the names don't collide (and that you are not confused by the state if the process fails in the middle). For example, you could name your original files: `catalog/orig_catalog_z1.5_{i:03d}.txt` and the destination `catalog/catalog_z1.5_{i:03d}.txt`, or have them in different directories.

Another way, if that's not an option, is to first rename them into a set of temp files:

```
import tempfile

prefix = tempfile.mktemp(prefix='.', dir=folder)
src, tmp, dst = zip(*[
    (f'{folder}/{folder}_z{z:.1f}_{i:03d}.txt',
     f'{prefix}-{folder}_z{z:.1f}_{i:03d}.txt',
     f'{folder}/{folder}_z{z:.1f}_{i+increment:03d}.txt')
    for i in range(start, end+1)
])

for a, b in zip(src + tmp, tmp + dst):
    print(f'{a} -> {b}')
    os.rename(a, b)
```

Output:

```
catalog/catalog_z1.5_000.txt -> catalog/.ns1opqyv-catalog_z1.5_000.txt
catalog/catalog_z1.5_001.txt -> catalog/.ns1opqyv-catalog_z1.5_001.txt
catalog/catalog_z1.5_002.txt -> catalog/.ns1opqyv-catalog_z1.5_002.txt
catalog/catalog_z1.5_003.txt -> catalog/.ns1opqyv-catalog_z1.5_003.txt
catalog/catalog_z1.5_004.txt -> catalog/.ns1opqyv-catalog_z1.5_004.txt
catalog/catalog_z1.5_005.txt -> catalog/.ns1opqyv-catalog_z1.5_005.txt
catalog/catalog_z1.5_006.txt -> catalog/.ns1opqyv-catalog_z1.5_006.txt
catalog/catalog_z1.5_007.txt -> catalog/.ns1opqyv-catalog_z1.5_007.txt
catalog/catalog_z1.5_008.txt -> catalog/.ns1opqyv-catalog_z1.5_008.txt
catalog/catalog_z1.5_009.txt -> catalog/.ns1opqyv-catalog_z1.5_009.txt
catalog/catalog_z1.5_010.txt -> catalog/.ns1opqyv-catalog_z1.5_010.txt
catalog/.ns1opqyv-catalog_z1.5_000.txt -> catalog/catalog_z1.5_005.txt
catalog/.ns1opqyv-catalog_z1.5_001.txt -> catalog/catalog_z1.5_006.txt
catalog/.ns1opqyv-catalog_z1.5_002.txt -> catalog/catalog_z1.5_007.txt
catalog/.ns1opqyv-catalog_z1.5_003.txt -> catalog/catalog_z1.5_008.txt
catalog/.ns1opqyv-catalog_z1.5_004.txt -> catalog/catalog_z1.5_009.txt
catalog/.ns1opqyv-catalog_z1.5_005.txt -> catalog/catalog_z1.5_010.txt
catalog/.ns1opqyv-catalog_z1.5_006.txt -> catalog/catalog_z1.5_011.txt
catalog/.ns1opqyv-catalog_z1.5_007.txt -> catalog/catalog_z1.5_012.txt
catalog/.ns1opqyv-catalog_z1.5_008.txt -> catalog/catalog_z1.5_013.txt
catalog/.ns1opqyv-catalog_z1.5_009.txt -> catalog/catalog_z1.5_014.txt
catalog/.ns1opqyv-catalog_z1.5_010.txt -> catalog/catalog_z1.5_015.txt
```

Comment: does this work for negative increment? (file number decreasing?)

Comment: Yes, it works for any increment. It works generally for any renaming transformation and in any order, as long as the `dst` names are unique (and the `src` ones too).

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if file number increases or decreases.

- If `increment  is +ve`, increase file number from last.
- If `increment is -ve`, decrease file number from start.

The implementation is shown below:

```py
import os

start = 10
end  = 20
increment = -5 # This should work for all eg. 5 ,-5, 50, etc.


folder = 'catalog'
z = 1.5


# create folder 
os.mkdirs('catalog',exist_ok=True)

# create files
for i in range(start,end+1):
    with open(f'catalog/catalog_z1.5_{i:03d}.txt','w') as fo:
        fo.write(str(i))

if increment > 0:
    for i in range(end,start-1,-1):
        f = '{}/{}_z{:.1f}_{:03d}.txt'.format(folder,folder,z,i)
        f2 = '{}/{}_z{:.1f}_{:03d}.txt'.format(folder,folder,z,i+increment)
        print(f'{f} -> {f2}')
        os.rename(f,f2)

else:
    for i in range(start,end+1,1):
        f = '{}/{}_z{:.1f}_{:03d}.txt'.format(folder,folder,z,i)
        f2 = '{}/{}_z{:.1f}_{:03d}.txt'.format(folder,folder,z,i+increment)
        print(f'{f} -> {f2}')
        os.rename(f,f2)
```

Comment: that is unsafe and will overwrite existing files with `str(i)` in them...

Comment: I am not sure how it is unsafe. For this simple example, I checked the outputs. The contents of files are unchanged, only the file name changes.

Comment: oh sorry -- I was looking at the first `for` loop and didn't realize it was copied over from the OP's code; I thought it was what you meant by "you have to check if the file number increases or decreases". All good.